# How do i access date: at {seconds: 1649365178, nanoseconds: 0} firebase firestore in react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, date, google-cloud-firestore

I am having trouble access this in my array. How should my syntax be?

```
date: at {seconds: 1649365178, nanoseconds: 0}
```

```
{entrylist.map((e, index) => {
   return <div key={index}>{e.date.seconds}</div>
})}
```

Thanks,

Comment: What isn't working about this code?

Comment: react-dom.development.js:11988 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'seconds')

I'm getting this. or this if i run {e.date}

react-dom.development.js:14703 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {seconds, nanoseconds}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: So it looks like `e.date` is `undefined`. Since we can't see how `entrylist` is initialized it's hard to be certain, but you might want to check whether the/all entries in that list really have a `data` property.

Comment: you're right! i had some test arrays from earlier that did not have the fields of date so that was stopping the code. thanks!

Comment: would be e.date.toDate()

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `e.date` is undefined. Since we can't see how `entrylist` is initialized it's hard to be certain, but you might want to check whether the/all entries in that list really have a `date` property.